# C# - Read bytes from file from a specific string

Tags: c#, file, filestream, binaryfiles

I'm trying to parse a [crg-file](http://opencrg.org/index.html) in C#. The file is mixed with plain text and binary data. The first section of the file contains plain text while the rest of the file is binary (lots of floats), here's an example:

```
$
$ROAD_CRG
reference_line_start_u   =  100
reference_line_end_u     =  120
$
$KD_DEFINITION
#:KRBI
U:reference line u,m,730.000,0.010
D:reference line phi,rad
D:long section 1,m
D:long section 2,m
D:long section 3,m
...
$
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
�@z����RAΣ����\�l
...
```

I know I can read bytes starting at a specific offset but how do I find out which byte to start from? The last row before the binary section will always contain at least four dollar signs "$$$$". Here's what I've got so far:

```
using var fs = new FileStream(@"crg_sample.crg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

var startByte = ??; // How to find out where to start?

using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(startByte, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var f = reader.ReadSingle();
    Debug.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Comment: Hook up a `StreamReader` with the `leaveOpen` constructor parameter set to `true`. Then you can simply read lines until you've seen the separator line and start using the `BinaryReader`, as the stream will be positioned correctly. Alternatively, of course, you can use the `BinaryReader` to hunt for four consecutive `0x24` bytes (`$`), then read to the next newline, then start reading floats (i.e. implement your own little state machine) but that's more complicated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert discussed more on Troy's answer, but: I don't think that works here

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yeah, obvious in hindsight when you take buffering into account, but also lame because it would not be *particularly* complicated for `StreamReader` to support this scenario anyway (given that we have a seekable stream). In the general case with buffered forward-only access you do have to get more complicated, of course.

Comment: OpenCRG doesn't seem to be very open or widespread - just 5 Github repos and only Mercedes is actually using this. Have you checked the C code? You may be able to replicate what it does using byte buffers or `Span<byte>`. Perhaps even map bytes to structs directly. Or you could use `System.IO.Pipelines` for an API that allows you to move back and forth in the file. You have to treat that files as binary though

Comment: You'll have to handle the file *differently* before and after the `$$$$$` lines. Is that separator well defined? If so, you can use one parser for everything up to it and a completely different one for the rest of the file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the tips, I believe it's defined well enough, it will be the only line with at least four consecutive '$' and on the next line the binary data will start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I know this is far from the most optimized solution but in my case it did the trick and since the plain text section of the file was known to be fairly small this didn't cause any noticable performance issues. Here's the code:

```
using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"crg_sample.crg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);

var newLine = '\n';
var markerString = "$$$$";
var currentString = "";

var foundMarker = false;
var foundNewLine = false;

while (!foundNewLine)
{
    var c = reader.ReadChar();

    if (!foundMarker)
    {
        currentString += c;

        if (currentString.Length > markerString.Length)
            currentString = currentString.Substring(1);

        if (currentString == markerString)
            foundMarker = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (c == newLine)
            foundNewLine = true;
    }
}

if (foundNewLine)
{
    // Read binary
}
```

**Note:** If you're dealing with larger or more complex files you should probably take a look at *Mark Gravell*'s answer and the comment sections.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a mixture of text data and binary data, you need to treat everything as binary. This means you should be using raw `Stream` access, or something similar, and using binary APIs to look through the text data (often looking for cr/lf/crlf at **bytes** as sentinels, although it sounds like in your case you could just look for the `$$$$` using binary APIs, then decode the entire block before, and scan forwards). When you think you have an entire line, then you can use `Encoding` to parse each line - the most convenient API being `encoding.GetString().` When you've finished looking through the text data *as binary*, *then* you can continue parsing the *binary* data, again using the binary API. I would *usually* recommend against `BinaryReader` here too, because frankly it doesn't gain you much over more direct API. The *other* problem you might want to think about is CPU endianness, but assuming that isn't a problem: `BitConverter.ToSingle()` may be your friend.

If the data is modest in size, you may find it easiest to use `byte[]` for the data; either via `File.ReadAllBytes`, or by renting an oversized `byte[]` from the array-pool, and loading it from a `FileStream`. The `Stream` API is awkward for this kind of scenario, because once you've looked at data: it has gone - so you need to maintain your own back-buffers. The *pipelines* API is ideal for this, when dealing with large data, but is an advanced topic.

Comment: Thanks for info and clues on how to move forward, it seems like this seemingly simple task isn't that simple after all. A question: by pipelines API, do you mean the built in System.IO.Pipelines?

Comment: @Johan yes; I have a multi-part blog on it - [starts here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) - the later sections have more code to look at

Comment: @Johan emphasis: there's no need to look at pipelines here unless the data is big; for modest data - just use `byte[]`, it'll be tons easier

Comment: Allright, what I know is that the plain text part will never be very large but the following binary could reach a pretty big size (up to GBs)

Comment: @Johan hmm; in that scenario, my next step would probably be to try using a memory mapped file with the block size at least as big as the largest expected first frame; perhaps [using this](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/master/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/MemoryMappedPipeReader.cs), but: I'm familiar (some would say *too* familiar) with the pipelines API, which can be daunting if you haven't touched it before. You could do some kind of "read from the stream byte by byte until you have all the text block, then decode the text block and continue the rest..."

Comment: @Johan "...as a stream", but: it won't be anywhere near as efficient as the memory mapped file approach

Comment: I added an answer with a solution which was enough for my needs, it finds where to start reading the binary quick enough, without me digging too deep into this.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** This code may not work as expected. Please review the valuable information in the comments.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"crg_sample.crg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII, true, 1, true))
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && !line.Contains("$$$$"))
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        // TODO: Start reading the binary data
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is *probably* broken; `StreamReader` over-reads, so you will have dropped data on the floor

Comment: @MarcGravell: that's a bummer. It's a shame it doesn't at least have a property for the virtual position of the stream so you could record/reset it manually.

Comment: This is not working since StreamReader jumps "bufferSize" amount of bytes (which is independent of the line length) and will position the reader too far ahead.

Comment: @JeroenMostert FWIW, that's one of the things I love about the "pipelines" API (which I've now added into my answer); it would be pretty trivial to parse this as a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`; but: not many people are familiar with that API

Comment: @MarcGravell would this code work if the buffer of the StreamReader were set to 1? If so would there be a significant negative impact on performance?

Comment: @TroyPalacino good question; don't know; it might not want to do that unless the encoding is ASCII, but: I've never tried

Comment: @TroyPalacino I gave it a try but apparently there's a minimum buffersize. According to the docs: "The buffer size, in number of 16-bit characters, is set by the bufferSize parameter. If bufferSize is less than the minimum allowable size (128 characters), the minimum allowable size is used."

Comment: @Johan I ran the code in .Net Core 2.1 without any error but I'm glad you found some code that worked for you.

Comment: @TroyPalacino Maybe it doesn't produce any error but it doesn't position the reader at the right spot either (which was the goal of this) unless it's exactly a multiple of 2*128 bytes before the binary begins. When you start reading the binary it will read from the wrong byte.